# Space Mono font converts </ to an arrow

Tags: macos, terminal, typography

[image: Screenshot]

I've been trying to use a Space Mono font for my terminal/neovim setup, but I've run into a curious issue where </ is automatically converted to an arrow. Screenshot is [from fonts.adobe.com](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/space-mono#fonts-section)

I'd like to be able to manually remove this effect...somehow because obviously any XML/HTML development is annoying/impossible with that rendering. Even if I can't, I'd like to know why this is working the way it is.

I thought at first it was an issue with terminal setup, but I've typed </ into both Google Fonts and Adobe Fonts with the same result.

Comment: This "effect" is called a ligature and is built in to the font. Some editors and applications understand fonts with ligatures. What terminal are you using, there may be a configuration setting to disable ligatures or even just single ones. (I tend to use FiraCode)

Comment: Excuse me, the default Mac terminal. There doesn't appear to be configuration options, but I can always try another one.